# change image background based on timezone - react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I am trying to change an image based on the timezone the app will ran. If the timezone is 5:00am, then the image to be shown should be a day image and if the timezone is 5:00pm, then the image to be shown is night.

Can anyone help me, I am trying to do this with react native expo.

Here is what I have tried but it doesn't seem to be helping me to solve the problem:

```
  //background image changer
  const imgArray = [images.bgNight, images.bgDay];

  const date = new Date();
  const time = date.getHours();
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(time);

  //time zone
  const timezone = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;
  console.log(timezone);

  const dayTime = date && time;
  dayTime.toLocaleString("en-US", timezone);
  console.log(dayTime);

  //save timer ref - set to 12 hour change (432000 sec)
  useEffect(() => {
    const imageTimerId = setInterval(() => {
      // dayTime < 12 ? setCounter(counter + 1) : counter - 1;
      if (dayTime <= 5) {
        setCounter(counter + 1);
      } else if (dayTime == 6 <= 18) {
        setCounter(counter + 1);
      } else {
        setCounter(counter + 1);
      }
    }, 432000);

    return () => clearInterval(imageTimerId);
  });

  // `image` is derived state from the image array
  const image = imgArray[counter % imgArray.length];
  console.log(image);
```

Your input and suggestions are highly appreciated, thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: I'm confused - time zones are not times, - they never have a value of 5pm.. Two questions as well please, why are you using time zone at all (instead of local time on the device), and do you want to change the image 12hours after the app is first run, or when locat time changes from some time interval chosen to represent day/night transitions?

Comment: Also, but probably a bug,  `if (dayTime == 6 <= 18)`  is true between 1 and 2am only,: the comparison operator takes precedence over the equality operator, and true (the value of 6 <= 18) and the number 1 are equivalent to each other in type conversions between numeric and boolean values.

Comment: @traktor I would like to change the image from 6 am and 6 pm, since you saw my issue, can you please help to achieve the aforementioned, so that the images change based on the time mentioned in this comment? 

Also been struggling to get the local time from the device, once I have that, then I will be able to achieve my goal. Thanks for your sound feedback. Looking forward to hearing from you again.

Answer (score 0):

#### Simplify where possible

If the requirement is only to change images at 0600 or 1800 hours, drop the timezone code and just use the time returned by `new Date()`, as exemplified by the `const date` declaration in posted code.

Consider changing some variable names and turning the image array into an object: "day" or "night" could be used as enumerable values of a `day_period` state (instead of "counter"), and used as array lookup values for an image URL object such as

```
const imgURLs = {night: images.bgNightURL, day images.bgDayURL};
```

(where key values are URL strings if not already).

#### Sample calculation of day/night

The following code demonstrates in vanilla JavaScript *one way* of obtaining a call back when local time transitions from night to day at 6am, or day to night to day at 6pm.

- The period value supplied to the callback is either "day" or "night" as a string value.
- The callback function is called synchronously when `updater` is first called, and asynchronously when transitions occur afterwards.
- The code checks for transitions every hour to automatically adjust for daylight savings.
- *The code snippet tests in seconds. Remove the lines with "TESTING in SECONDS" comments, remove the console.log, and un-comment the commented lines which use hourly values if running an app.*
- This is example code. Direct implementation in React should take care to avoid calling `setState` functions in a component constructor if doing so is not permitted.

```js
"use strict";
class DayPeriod {
  constructor() {
    this.notify = true;
    this.period = null; // unknown
    // this.checkInterval = 60*60*1000; // 1 hour
    this.checkInterval = 1000; // TESTING in SECONDS
    this.updater = this.updater.bind(this);
  }
  periodOf( date) {
    // const hour = date.getHours();
    const hour = ++testHours % 24; // TESTING in SECONDS:
    console.log("hour " + hour);
    return (hour < 6 || hour >= 18) ? "night" : "day";
  }
  setPeriod( date) {
    const period = this.periodOf( date);
    this.notify = period !== this.period;
    this.period = period;
  }
  updater( callBack) {
    const date = new Date(); // current date and time
    this.setPeriod( date);
    if( this.notify) {
       callBack( this.period);
       this.notify = false;
    }
    const time = date.getTime();
    const delay = this.checkInterval - time%this.checkInterval;
    setTimeout( this.updater, delay, callBack);
  }
}

/************ test updater ************/

var testHours = 0; // see "TESTING in SECONDS" comments in DayPeriod class

// start a call back to `function(period)` on change of day period.

let currentPeriod = "night"; 

new DayPeriod().updater(
  function (period) {
    console.log("period update: ", period);
    // get React to re-render the image for the updated state.
    currentPeriod = period;
    // ...
  }
)
```

#### Rendering updated images.

Calling a `setState` function obtained from [`useState(...)`](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#adding-state-to-a-component)  should trigger re-rendering the image. Writing JSX to update the image source from the state value (`currentPeriod` in the code snippet) is outside my area of expertise, although I strongly suspect you would **not** use `useEffect` for this at all.

Please ask a new question if you need to solve how to render the image with a new URL (to assist readers looking for solutions to the same problem).